# Matching Checkboxes By Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

I have a list of checkboxes, I'm trying to check these based on the value of a textbox.

```
var codes = $('#textbox1').val().split(','); // this contains [ "Dept1" and "Dept2" ]
var allDeptChecks = $('.Dept-help input:checkbox'); // this contains all of my checkboxes
allDeptChecks.attr('checked', false);
$.each(codes, function() {
    var chkDept = allDeptChecks.find("[value='"+this+"']"); // no matter what I try, this selector matches 0 elements
    chkDept.attr('checked', true);
}); 

<li title="Dept 1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkDept1" value="Dept1">
    <span>Dept1</span>
    <span>Description Numero Uno</span>
</li>
<li title="Dept 2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkDept2" value="Dept2">
    <span>Dept2</span>
    <span>Description Numero Dos</span>
</li>
```

Shouldn't this work?

**EDIT:** [Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qwd6M/)

Comment: Could you provide a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
$('#lnkGo').click(function () {
    var codes = $('#textbox1').val().split(','); // this contains [ "Dept1" and "Dept2" ]
    var allDeptChecks = $('input:checkbox'); // this contains all of my checkboxes
    allDeptChecks.prop('checked', false);
    $.each(codes, function () {
        var chkDept = allDeptChecks.filter("input[value='" + this + "']"); // no matter what I try, this selector matches 0 elements
        chkDept.prop('checked', true);
    });
});
```

Comment: change .find to .filter.  I also changed chkDept.attr('checked', true) to chkDept.attr('checked', 'checked') and for sanity sake I added 'input' to your filter selector.

Comment: I updated the code to use prop instead of attr because the second time you clicked go it would remove the checkboxes.

Comment: Thanks, I've [written a blog post on this](http://www.leghumped.com/blog/2013/01/24/synchonising-a-textbox-and-checkbox-list/). Using `prop` instead of `attr` did make a difference - the latter didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$.each(codes, function(i, value) {
$("input[value='"+value+"']").prop('checked', true);    
});
```